# Interactive Report Pivot, ORA-06502

Tags: oracle-apex

I created Interactive Report, it contains about 2k rows, there is all okey, but I have problem with Pivot. If more than 170 rows I get error "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small", if less than 170 it works. Where is problem?

```
Pivot Columns: Zone;
Row Columns: Question;
Functions: Count (value 0/1; + sum), Average (value 0-100).
```

Edit: if I delete one functions then pivot is without error. Error when more than 100 columns.

Comment: Can't tell for sure (as I don't know it), but - it seems you hit some Apex limitation. What to do? Well, do you *really* need over 100 columns? Who's going to look at 100 columns x 2000 rows on the screen and conclude something useful out of it? Can't you *shorten* it (the report) a little bit?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write that in table about 2k records and if I displaying only 170 of them, Pivot is okey. Interactive Report displays all of them (2k, and there is okey), but Pivot must displays 10 rows and 246 columns (and inside 2 functions for each column). Yes, I can make it shorten till ~50 columns. Where I can check about Apex limitations?

Comment: Somewhere in documentation, I presume. I don't have a link.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I try to find it. I think this question is solved.